# Header in fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

Alright, so I'm using `fancyhdr` with the default options. I have some sections, where I'd like it to appear different in the TOC. This is accomplished like so:

```
\section[test (in the TOC)]{test}
```

In the header made by `fancyhdr`, the section is shown in the same way as in the TOC (`test (in the TOC)`) and not the way it's shown at the section itself (`test`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section[test (in the TOC)]{test}

test

\end{document}
```

I'd like the header to say `test` not `test (in the TOC)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the mark by

```
\markboth{\thesection.\ test}{}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\newpage


\section[test (in the TOC)]{test}
\markboth{\thesection.\ test}{}


test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to switch to a class with this feature built in.

The appearence is a bit different, KOMA-script aims to provide nice defaults for the non-north-american world.

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}%KOMA-budle
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section[test (in the TOC)]{test}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```